# TreeViewItem: How to make selection change occur on Click instead of MouseDown?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, treeview, selection

Background: I am implementing Drag&Drop from a TreeView. A requirement is that dragging an item should *not* change the selection - only a complete Click (MouseUp on the same item) should select that item.

However, the default behavior of the TreeView is to raise a SelectedItemChanged event on MouseDown. Any idea on how to change that?

Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention an important point - my apologies. I am using the [Gong drag&drop framework](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/) for all drag&drop operations, since it blends very well with MVVM (no code-behind needed in my Views). The drag&drop logic is handled entirely in the ViewModels, via attached properties in the Views' XAML.

Therefore, solutions involving `PreviewMouseDown` and handling all the selection and drag logic myself would be counter-productive. So I am just looking for a (simple) way to prevent the TreeView control from changing the selection already on mouse down, while still raising the usual bubbling events like `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` etc. in order for the drag&drop library to work as designed.

My next idea would be to modify the Gong drag&drop library code myself - I was just hoping I can avoid that, and someone would come up with an easy way to change the TreeView's behavior in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [tunneling events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) like `PreviewMouseDown` on the `TreeViewItems`, those will be handled before the event reaches the internals of the control, hence you can intercept them by setting `e.Handled = true`. Use this event in connection with the tunneling versions of `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` to implement some custom dragging and selection logic.

You may need to intercept all events and select manually if there is no drag but maybe you can work out something better or more elegant. I hope this helps you in getting this done.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I had thought of that already, but unfortunately it won't work in my case, since I'm deferring the drag&drop handling to the [Gong drag&drop library](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/). I've edited my original post to add that info.